# Which parts of this water shader are resposible for the transparancy?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl

I have a water shader here and I want to know what code is responsible for transparency.

Currently the water is transparent, that is the other thing i would like to change. I hoped the RenderType is "RenderType"="transparent" but it is "RenderType"="Opaque" .... and i couldn't find transparent code in this shader.

Maybe you know the parts of the code causes the transparency?

This is the water shader

```
Shader "FX/Water" {
 Properties {
     _WaveScale ("Wave scale", Range (0.02,0.15)) = 0.063
     _ReflDistort ("Reflection distort", Range (0,1.5)) = 0.44
     _RefrDistort ("Refraction distort", Range (0,1.5)) = 0.40
     _RefrColor ("Refraction color", COLOR)  = ( .34, .85, .92, 1)
     [NoScaleOffset] _Fresnel ("Fresnel (A) ", 2D) = "gray" {}
     [NoScaleOffset] _BumpMap ("Normalmap ", 2D) = "bump" {}
     WaveSpeed ("Wave speed (map1 x,y; map2 x,y)", Vector) = (19,9,-16,-7)
     [NoScaleOffset] _ReflectiveColor ("Reflective color (RGB) fresnel (A)", 2D) = "" {}
     _HorizonColor ("Simple water horizon color", COLOR)  = ( .172, .463, .435, 1)
     [HideInInspector] _ReflectionTex ("Internal Reflection", 2D) = "" {}
     [HideInInspector] _RefractionTex ("Internal Refraction", 2D) = "" {}

     //
     _EmissionColor("Color", Color) = (0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,1.000000)
     _EmissionMap("Emission", 2D) = "white" { }
     [Toggle] _DynamicEmissionLM("Dynamic Emission (Lightmapper)", Int) = 0
 }


 // -----------------------------------------------------------
 // Fragment program cards


 Subshader {
     Tags { "WaterMode"="Refractive" "RenderType"="Opaque" }
     Pass {
 CGPROGRAM
 #pragma vertex vert
 #pragma fragment frag
 #pragma multi_compile_fog
 #pragma multi_compile WATER_REFRACTIVE WATER_REFLECTIVE WATER_SIMPLE

 #if defined (WATER_REFLECTIVE) || defined (WATER_REFRACTIVE)
 #define HAS_REFLECTION 1
 #endif
 #if defined (WATER_REFRACTIVE)
 #define HAS_REFRACTION 1
 #endif


 #include "UnityCG.cginc"

 uniform float4 _WaveScale4;
 uniform float4 _WaveOffset;

 #if HAS_REFLECTION
 uniform float _ReflDistort;
 #endif
 #if HAS_REFRACTION
 uniform float _RefrDistort;
 #endif

 struct appdata {
     float4 vertex : POSITION;
     float3 normal : NORMAL;
 };

 struct v2f {
     float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
     #if defined(HAS_REFLECTION) || defined(HAS_REFRACTION)
         float4 ref : TEXCOORD0;
         float2 bumpuv0 : TEXCOORD1;
         float2 bumpuv1 : TEXCOORD2;
         float3 viewDir : TEXCOORD3;
     #else
        float2 bumpuv0 : TEXCOORD0;
         float2 bumpuv1 : TEXCOORD1;
         float3 viewDir : TEXCOORD2;
     #endif
     UNITY_FOG_COORDS(4)
 };

 v2f vert(appdata v)
 {
     v2f o;
     o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);


     // scroll bump waves
     float4 temp;
     float4 wpos = mul (unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex);
     //temp.xyzw = wpos.xzxz * _WaveScale4 + _WaveOffset;
     temp.xyzw = wpos.yzyz * _WaveScale4 + _WaveOffset;
     o.bumpuv0 = temp.xy;
     o.bumpuv1 = temp.wz;

     // object space view direction (will normalize per pixel)
     o.viewDir.xzy = WorldSpaceViewDir(v.vertex);

     #if defined(HAS_REFLECTION) || defined(HAS_REFRACTION)
     o.ref = ComputeNonStereoScreenPos(o.pos);
     #endif

     UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.pos);
     return o;
 }

 #if defined (WATER_REFLECTIVE) || defined (WATER_REFRACTIVE)
 sampler2D _ReflectionTex;
 #endif
 #if defined (WATER_REFLECTIVE) || defined (WATER_SIMPLE)
 sampler2D _ReflectiveColor;
 #endif
 #if defined (WATER_REFRACTIVE)
 sampler2D _Fresnel;
 sampler2D _RefractionTex;
 uniform float4 _RefrColor;
 #endif
 #if defined (WATER_SIMPLE)
 uniform float4 _HorizonColor;
 #endif
 sampler2D _BumpMap;

 half4 frag( v2f i ) : SV_Target
 {
     i.viewDir = normalize(i.viewDir);

     // combine two scrolling bumpmaps into one
     half3 bump1 = UnpackNormal(tex2D( _BumpMap, i.bumpuv0 )).rgb;
     half3 bump2 = UnpackNormal(tex2D( _BumpMap, i.bumpuv1 )).rgb;
     half3 bump = (bump1 + bump2) * 0.5;

     // fresnel factor
     half fresnelFac = dot( i.viewDir, bump );

     // perturb reflection/refraction UVs by bumpmap, and lookup colors

     #if HAS_REFLECTION
     float4 uv1 = i.ref; uv1.xy += bump * _ReflDistort;
     half4 refl = tex2Dproj( _ReflectionTex, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(uv1) );
     #endif
     #if HAS_REFRACTION
     float4 uv2 = i.ref; uv2.xy -= bump * _RefrDistort;
     half4 refr = tex2Dproj( _RefractionTex, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(uv2) ) * _RefrColor;
     #endif

     // final color is between refracted and reflected based on fresnel
     half4 color;

 #if defined(WATER_REFRACTIVE)
     half fresnel = UNITY_SAMPLE_1CHANNEL( _Fresnel,         
      float2(fresnelFac,fresnelFac) );
     color = lerp( refr, refl, fresnel );
     #endif

     #if defined(WATER_REFLECTIVE)
     half4 water = tex2D( _ReflectiveColor, float2(fresnelFac,fresnelFac) );
     color.rgb = lerp( water.rgb, refl.rgb, water.a );
     color.a = refl.a * water.a;
     #endif

     #if defined(WATER_SIMPLE)
     half4 water = tex2D( _ReflectiveColor, float2(fresnelFac,fresnelFac) );
     color.rgb = lerp( water.rgb, _HorizonColor.rgb, water.a );
     color.a = _HorizonColor.a;
     #endif

     UNITY_APPLY_FOG(i.fogCoord, color);

     //o.Emission = c.rgb * tex2D(_Illum, IN.uv_Illum).a;


     return color;
 }
 ENDCG

     }
 }

 }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. **Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once**. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: i try to edit it but i have two problems and i showed them in the text. I need to add a emission to that shader and need to know wich code is responisble for the transparacy. fotr that the person need the shade code to help me. i hope its better now

Comment: I've edited the question to make it about a single specific problem so that it isn't too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#pragma multi_compile WATER_REFRACTIVE WATER_REFLECTIVE WATER_SIMPLE` line allows the script to have different modes depending on global configuration. From the documentation:

> **How multi_compile works**
>
> Example directive:
>
> ```
> #pragma multi_compile FANCY_STUFF_OFF FANCY_STUFF_ON
> ```
>
> This example directive produces two shader variants: one with FANCY_STUFF_OFF defined, and another with FANCY_STUFF_ON. At run time, Unity activates one of them based on the Material or global shader keywords. If neither of these two keywords are enabled, then Unity uses the first one (in this example, FANCY_STUFF_OFF).

So in the case of this question, `WATER_REFRACTIVE` is enabled by default.

If you look at the fragment shader, you'll see this `#ifdefined` section:

```
#if defined(WATER_REFRACTIVE)
half fresnel = UNITY_SAMPLE_1CHANNEL( _Fresnel,         
float2(fresnelFac,fresnelFac) );
color = lerp( refr, refl, fresnel );
#endif
```

To answer your immediate question, the transparency effect is where the refractive color `refr` is visible over the reflective color `refl`, which is determined by the `_Fresnel` and `_BumpMap` textures.

You *could* make the water totally reflective by changing the shader here to just use `color = refl;` instead.

However, another way of doing it starts with changing the mode of the shader by using [`Material.EnableKeyword`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.EnableKeyword.html) on the water's `Material` to enable the `WATER_SIMPLE` keyword:

```cs
water.material.EnableKeyword("WATER_SIMPLE");
```

Doing this will use this `#ifdefined` section in the vertex shader instead of the previously mentioned one:

```
#if defined(WATER_SIMPLE)
half4 water = tex2D( _ReflectiveColor, float2(fresnelFac,fresnelFac) );
color.rgb = lerp( water.rgb, _HorizonColor.rgb, water.a );
color.a = _HorizonColor.a;
#endif
```

and we can see that it sets the output color's alpha  as `_HorizonColor.a`. This means that with this mode, you would be able to set the water's transparency directly by changing the alpha of `_HorizonColor`

Comment: nice extensive answer :) the short version though is "this shader is not transparent" (it just looks like it because it displays a captured texture of what's behind)

Comment: great answer thaks a lot that helped a lot